# NetLogo: How to pull coordinates from neighboring patches based on patch-variable

Tags: netlogo

I have limited programming experience (mechanical engineering student, so a bit of matlab and labview experience) and am very new to NetLogo, so I apologize in advance if this question is pretty basic or my code is of poor quality.

I need to have my turtles move to 1 of 2 possible neighboring patches based on a given probability function. The two patches that I need to input to the probability function are the two neighboring patches with the lowest nest-scent value. I have been able to pull the two lowest nest-scent values, but I cannot figure out how to actually figure out which patches those are, and how to put those coordinates into an ifelse statement to move the turtle to one of them based on the aformentioned probability function. I have the following code that is obviously not working:

```
    to move
  set farthest-patch sort-by < [nest-scent] of neighbors
  let a1x pxcor of item 0 farthest-patch
  let a1y pycor of item 0 farthest-patch
  let a2x pxcor of item 1 farthest-patch
  let a2y pycor of item 1 farthest-patch
  let a1 item 0 farthest-patch
  let a2 item 1 farthest-patch
  let x (((a1 + a2) / 100 ) - 1)
  let probability-move 0.5 * (1 + ((exp(x) - exp( - x)) / (exp(x) + exp( - x))))
  ifelse random-float 1 < probability-move
  [set to-move 1]
  [set to-move 0]
  let a1-probability (a1 / (a1 + a2))
  ifelse random-float 1 < a1-probability
    [set destination [a1x a1y]]
    [set destination [a2x a2y]]
    ifelse count turtles-here >= 20
    [set full 1]
    [set full 0]
  if [a1x a21] = full
  [set destination [a2x a2y]]
  if [a2x a2y] = full
  [set destination [a1x a1y]]
  if [a2x a2y] and [a1x a1y] = full
  [set to-move 0]
  ifelse to-move = 1
  [move-to destination]
  [stop]
end
```

Basically what I have (tried) to do here is sort a farthest-patches list by increasing nest-scent, and I have pulled the two lowest nest-scent values in order to input those values into my probability functions (both for whether or not to move, and if they are to move which of the two patches to select). I am not sure how to properly pull the patch coordinates of the patches that the a1 and a2 values were taken from.

Thanks for any help,

Brad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay, you are making life way more complicated than it needs to be. You can select the two patches (or turtles) with the smallest values of a variable with `min-n-of`. Look it up in the dictionary to get the details.

Having found the two candidates, the best option is to use the `rnd` extension for choosing the destination because it has a primitive for random selection by weight. Finally, since you are using a function of your variable as the weight (rather than the variable value itself), you need a way to construct that weight. The best option is to separate it out - you could also have a second variable with the weight value, but that just proliferates variables.

Here is a complete working model. Please copy the whole thing into a new instance of NetLogo and try and understand how it works, rather than just copy the relevant bits into your code because `min-n-of`, using agentsets and passing variables to procedures are important aspects of NetLogo that you need to know about. I have also set up colouring etc so you can see the choices it makes.

```
extensions [rnd]

patches-own [ nest-scent ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 1 [ set color red ]
  ask patches
  [ set nest-scent random 100
    set plabel nest-scent
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask one-of turtles [ move ]
  tick
end

to move
  set pcolor blue
  let targets min-n-of 2 neighbors [ nest-scent ]
  let destination rnd:weighted-one-of targets [ calc-weight nest-scent ]
  move-to destination
end

to-report calc-weight [ XX ]
  let weight 0.5 * (1 + ((exp(XX) - exp( - XX)) / (exp(XX) + exp( - XX))))
  report weight
end
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I had a feeling that I was going about this in a poor manner. Really appreciate the help.